# Show $I$ prime implies that for left ideals $J,K$ $JK \subset I$ then $J \subset I$ or $K \subset I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a ring and $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$. Show that if $J,K$ are left ideals of $R$, then $JK \subset I \implies J \subset I$ or $K \subset I$.

I am given a hint to show that the set $A=\{a \in R \mid aK \subset I\}$ is an ideal containing $J$. I did this and will spare the details unless requested.

Now we suppose $j \in J-I$. Then $JK \subset I$ implies $jK \subset I$. So for all $k \in K$ we have $jk=i$ for some $i \in I$. Since $I$ is prime, $K \subset I$.

Now suppose $k' \in K-I$. Then $k'J \subset J \subset A$ so for all $k \in K$ and $j \in J$, $k'jk \in I$.
In particular $(k'j)k' = i$ for some $i \in I$. Then by primeness again we see that $k'j \in I$ and finally $j \in I$ for all $j \in J$.

This looks convincing (if not rather inelegant) to me but why did I go though the trouble of showing $A$ was an ideal?

Comment: I guess your teacher wanted you to use the quotient $R/I$.

Comment: Can you say if my proof is correct? Also say more about that argument? I did consider things like this but kept getting stuck. A full proof is not necessary or even wanted.

Comment: Why is $A$ an ideal?

Comment: @JCAA Because $K$ is a left ideal

Comment: Ok. How do you define prime ideals? The property in the title is one of the definitions.

Comment: @JCAA The third paragraph indicates his definition of a prime ideal and it also indicates that Muselive assumes $R$ has 1.

Comment: I'm not meant to assume untiality. Can you explain why this is so/

Comment: I think the source of confusion here is that I'm mixing up definitions of prime. D&F only defines it for commutative rings and that's what I've been studying from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks like you began to suspect at the end of your comments, you are not using the definition of 'prime' appropriate to the context.  For noncommutative rings, [here are versions of the definition of prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings).

In the third paragraph, you assume the commutative definition of a prime ideal, which is too strong, and so the conclusion does not follow (for noncommutative rings.)

From the hint given, I believe you want to use the basic definition of a noncommutative prime ideal, which is that $I\neq R$ and that the product of two ideals being contained in $I$ implies that one of the ideal is contained in $I$.  That means the task here is to prove one of the equivalences in the link above, that you can replace two-sided ideals with one-sided ideals.

So, you proved that $A=\{a\mid aK\subseteq I\}$ is an ideal containing $J$. We also have $AK\subseteq I$.  Then by the same token $B=\{b\mid Ab\subseteq I\}$ is an ideal containing $K$ such that $AB\subseteq I$.  Now apply the basic definition of a noncommutative prime ideal, and you are basically done.